# How can I have multiple conditions for different jobs inside a job that needs them?

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a reusable workflow having three jobs: job1, job2 and job3.

The conditions I wish to meet are:

1. job3 needs to always run after the successful completion of job2 hence I mention `needs: [job1,job2]` in job3.
2. job3 should run if job2 is skipped
3. job3 should always depend on / need job1 to run.

Below is my workflow:

```
on:

  workflow_call:

    inputs:

        enable_scan:
          required: false
          type: boolean
          default: true 

        runner_name:
          required: false
          type: string
          default: 'myselfhostedrunner' 

jobs:

 

  job1:

    runs-on: '${{ inputs.runner_name }}'
    outputs:
      myrunner: '${{ inputs.runner_name }}'

    steps:

      - name: Runner details
        run: |
          echo "Job1 called"

  job2:

  if: inputs.enable_scan

    runs-on: '${{ inputs.runner_name }}'

    steps:

      - name: Runner details
        run: |
          echo "Job2 called"

  job3:

    runs-on: '${{ needs.job1.outputs.myrunner }}'

    needs: [job1, job2]
    if: ${{ ! success() && ! cancelled() }}

    steps:

      - name: Checkout folderX
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
```

How can I meet 2 different requirements for job1 and job2 inside job3?

Answer (score 1):

You have

```bash
 job1 --[always]--> job3
 job2 --[success]--> job3
```

Based on the configuration you provided and the conditions you want to meet, you might consider:

- adjusting the `if` statement in job3 to check if job2 is either skipped or successful.
- using GitHub Actions' conditional `if` syntax to create the logic that will allow job3 to run under the desired conditions.
- making sure job3 always runs after job1 by keeping `needs: [job1, job2]` in job3 definition.
- use [outputs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/defining-outputs-for-jobs) from `job2` to signal whether `job3` should run or not.

For instance:

```yaml
on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      enable_scan:
        required: false
        type: boolean
        default: true 
      runner_name:
        required: false
        type: string
        default: 'myselfhostedrunner' 

jobs:
  job1:
    runs-on: '${{ inputs.runner_name }}'
    outputs:
      myrunner: '${{ inputs.runner_name }}'
    steps:
      - name: Runner details
        run: |
          echo "Job1 called"

  job2:
    if: inputs.enable_scan
    runs-on: '${{ inputs.runner_name }}'
    outputs:
      status: ${{ steps.check-status.outputs.status }}  # Set an output to signal the status of this job to job3
    steps:
      - name: Runner details
        run: |
          echo "Job2 called"
      - id: check-status
        run: echo "status=completed" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT  # Update to use GITHUB_OUTPUT environment file

  job3:
    runs-on: '${{ needs.job1.outputs.myrunner }}'
    needs: [job1, job2]
    if: ${{ fromJson(needs.job2.outputs.status).status == 'completed' || needs.job2.result == 'SKIPPED' }}  # Check the status output from job2
    steps:
      - name: Checkout folderX
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
```

Now, job3 will execute if job2 is skipped or successful, and it will always depend on job1.

```
 job1 --[always]--> job3
 job2 --[success or skipped]--> job3
```

---

A possible alternative is to use artifacts, to pass data between `job2` and `job3`:

```yaml
on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      enable_scan:
        required: false
        type: boolean
        default: true 
      runner_name:
        required: false
        type: string
        default: 'myselfhostedrunner' 

jobs:
  job1:
    runs-on: '${{ inputs.runner_name }}'
    steps:
      - name: Runner details
        run: |
          echo "Job1 called"

  job2:
    if: inputs.enable_scan
    runs-on: '${{ inputs.runner_name }}'
    steps:
      - name: Runner details
        run: |
          echo "Job2 called"
      - name: Set status
        id: set-status
        run: echo "completed" > status.txt
      - name: Upload status
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: status
          path: status.txt

  job3:
    runs-on: '${{ needs.job1.outputs.myrunner }}'
    needs: [job1, job2]
    steps:
      - name: Download status
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: status
      - name: Check status
        id: check-status
        run: |
          if [[ -f status.txt ]]; then
            STATUS=$(cat status.txt)
          else
            STATUS="SKIPPED"
          fi
          echo "::set-output name=status::$STATUS"
      - name: Conditional step
        if: ${{ steps.check-status.outputs.status == 'completed' || needs.job2.result == 'SKIPPED' }}
        run: |
          echo "Job3 running..."
```

Comment: sorry but i tested you answer and it skips both job2 and job3 incase `enable_scan: false` so condition 2 is not met -> `job3 should run if job2 is skipped`... Here is my test run -> sample action `https://github.com/knowyrtech/getvarfromreusuable/actions/runs/6685709063/job/18164294986` where both job2 and job3 gets skipped

Comment: i tried both upper and lower case checks i.e `if: ${{ needs.job2.result == 'skipped'  but job3 does not run upon skipping job2

Comment: @Ashar OK. Maybe using outputs from job2 to signal whether job3 should run or not would work. I have updated the answer.

Comment: i tried the first part of your answer [preferred] using `outputs` and it still does not work. Sample run here: https://github.com/knowyrtech/getvarfromreusuable/actions/runs/6685966296

Comment: @Ashar OK. I will have a look tomorrow